# How write and append data in csv file and store it in list

Tags: python, list, csv, append

I made csv file in my python code itself and going to append next data in ti it but the error is comming

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

I tried code is:

```
df.to_csv('timepass.csv', index=False)
with open(r'timepass.csv', 'a') as f:
       writer = csv.reader(f)
       your_list = list(writer)
       print(your_list)
```

want to append next data and store in the same csv file. so that csv file having both previous and current data.
so please help me to find out..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox as it also helps and motivates the community.

Comment: Error is comming sir......AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'readlines

Comment: I edited my answer for the `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open(r'timepass.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))

print(reader)
```

Here you are opening your file as `r`, which means read-only and assigning the list contents to `reader` with `list(csv.reader(f))`. Your earlier code `a` opens the file for appending only where in the documentation is described as:

> 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is
>   automatically added to the end

and does not support the `read()`.

And if you want to append data to the csv file from a different list, use the with open as `a` with the `writer` method.

```
with open('lake.csv','a') as f:
    csv.writer(f,[1,2,3]) #dummy list [1,2,3]
```

Or directly from the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` method from your new dataframe, with `header = False` so as not to append headers:

```
df.to_csv('timepass.csv', index=False)
df_new.to_csv(r'timepass.csv', mode='a', header=False) #once you have updated your dataframe, you can directly append it to the same csv file
```

Comment: by your way. error is : AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'readlines'. want to store data in list format also. as i mention in question.

Comment: Apologies `readlines()` does not apply to the `csv` module. You can use `reader`.

Comment: with open('lake.csv','a') as l:
    reader = csv.writer(l,[1,2,3]) #dummy list [1,2,3]

the out put is:  <_csv.writer object at 0x7f521cd17e08>

Comment: `csv.writer` is the object that is used to write. Refer to the edited response. The list you are writing is the dummy list. If you are writing, it makes sense if you already know what you are writing, in the example, it wod be the dummy list.

Comment: df.to_csv('timepass.csv', index=False)
df_new.to_csv(r'timepass.csv', mode='a', header=False) , by this way you writting file two time not appending

Comment: Read the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), the `to_csv` method supports Python's write modes which allows for appending with `a`.

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple just try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("NSTT.xlsx","Sheet1")  #reading Excel 

print(df)    #Printing data frame 

df.to_excel("new.xlsx")    #Writing Dataframe into New Excel file
```

Now here if you want to append data in the same file then use

```
df.to_excel("new.xlsx","a")
```

And no need to add in a list as you can directly access the data same as a list with data frame only you have to define the location .

Comment: Need for csv file not excel

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas for appending two csv quickly

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe1=pd.read_csv("a.csv")
dataframe2=pd.read_csv("b.csv")
dataframe1=dataframe1.append(dataframe2)
dataframe1=dataframe1.reset_index(drop=True)
dataframe1.to_csv("a.csv")
```

Comment: @royal if u replace the path with dataframe1.to_csv("a,csv")  then a.csv becomes main csv file with all data's if u have any other csv file to add just change b.csv with the new file name

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://realpython.com/python-csv/).

You can use pandas in python to read csv and write csv:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("csv file")

print(df)
```

Comment: by your way, Overwritting data in csv